# Error indefino en JQuery Ajax DataTables

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

estoy intentando programar una tabla dinámica que se cargue con una petición ajax realizada en jquery. El objetivo es que quiero cargar datos en una tabla (DataTables) con datos de una base de datos de acuerdo a una consulta. En mi función si puedo recuperar los datos, pero el problema es mostrarlos en la tabla. Obtengo varios errores. Agradecería mucho, si puedieran ayudarme o si alguien ha tenido algún problema similiar. Gracias de antemano.

Esta es el código de la petición ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#select_contrato').change(function () {
    $('#c031_table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/clausulas031_contrato/" + $(this).val(),
            data: {
                "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
            },
            method: 'POST',
            dataSrc: "clausulas"
        },//This is the end of the AJAX object from the example above
        columns: [
            { data: 'numero' },
            { data: 'nombre' },
            { data: 'descripcion' },
            { data: 'estandar' },
            { data: 'contrato_id' }
        ]
    });
  });
});
```

El resultado de la consulta que realiza la función es este:

```
{
"clausulas":
[
    { "numero": "Primero", "nombre": "Objeto del contrato", "descripcion": "\"EL CONTRATISTA\" prestar\u00e1 los servicios siguientes: OPERADOR DE EQUIPO DE ESTAD\u00cdSTICA, en el Unidad de Tecnolog\u00edas de la Informaci\u00f3n, desempe\u00f1ando las siguientes funciones: a) Llevar registro digital de la documentaci\u00f3n que ingresa al Departamento; b) Realizar el escaneo y archivo de toda la documentaci\u00f3n que ingresa y egresa del Departamento; c) Conformaci\u00f3n de expedientes administrativos solicitados al Departamento; d) Elaborar bases de datos de los renglones presupuestario 022, 031, 029 y 021;  d) Las actividades descritas son enunciativas m\u00e1s no limitativas, por lo que \u201cEL CONTRATISTA\u201d deber\u00e1 desarrollar todas aquellas otras actividades que se deriven de la presente contrataci\u00f3n.", "estandar": 0, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "Segundo", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "La relaci\u00f3n de trabajo se inicia el trece [13] de octubre de dos mil veintid\u00f3s [2022] y finalizar\u00e1 el treinta y uno [31] de diciembre de dos mil veintid\u00f3s [2022].", "estandar": 0, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "Cuarto", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "\u201cEL CONTRATISTA\u201d prestar\u00e1 sus servicios en una jornada de ocho (8) horas.", "estandar": 0, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "Quinto", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "\u201cEL CONTRATISTA\u201d devengara un jornal diario de setenta y tres quetzales con cincuenta y nueve centavos [Q73.59], m\u00e1s doscientos cincuenta quetzales [Q250.00] mensuales, seg\u00fan Acuerdo Gubernativo n\u00famero sesenta y seis gui\u00f3n dos mil [66-2000], m\u00e1s seiscientos cincuenta y cuatro quetzales [Q654.00] mensuales, seg\u00fan Acuerdos Ministeriales n\u00famero un mil ochocientos ochenta y uno gui\u00f3n dos mil diecis\u00e9is [1881-2016] y un mil ochocientos ochenta y uno gui\u00f3n dos mil diecis\u00e9is [1318-2021] \u201cBono Monetario por Ajuste al Salario M\u00ednimo\u201d, que se pagar\u00e1 cada mes en la cuenta de dep\u00f3sitos monetarios aperturada en el Banco del Cr\u00e9dito Hipotecario Nacional  o en el banco que se le asigne.", "estandar": 0, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "Sexto", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "\u201cEL CONTRATISTA\u201d se somete a lo dispuesto en la Ley de Servicio Civil y normas aplicables en materia de administraci\u00f3n de personal y a cumplir las \u00f3rdenes e instrucciones que reciba de conformidad con la Ley.", "estandar": 0, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "Tercero", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "Este contrato podr\u00e1 ser rescindido: a) Por ocurrir las causas estipuladas en la Ley de Servicio Civil; b) Reorganizaci\u00f3n; c) Reducci\u00f3n forzosa de servicios; d) Falta de fondos en la partida presupuestaria; e) Por mutuo acuerdo; f) Renuncia; g) Vencimiento del plazo contractual; h) Caso fortuito o fuerza mayor, e, i) Otros.", "estandar": 1, "contrato_id": 1 },
    { "numero": "S\u00e9ptimo", "nombre": null, "descripcion": "Le\u00eddo lo anterior, enterados de su contenido, objeto, validez y efectos legales, lo aceptamos, ratificamos y firmamos.", "estandar": 1, "contrato_id": 1 }]
}
```

Pero al momento de renderizar los campos en la tabla. Me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho que puedan apoyarme. Saludos.

Comment: cómo intentas listar la tabla? donde está la propiedad `length`?

Comment: Parece que estas armando datatables antes que cargue Jquery, ¿como los tienes cargados?

Comment: @Robinson en el index tengo un select que llama a una funcion en mi controller. esa funcion me retorna un json (el que adjunté en la pregunta). No se si eso a es a lo que te refieres.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev entiendo que en la parte del codigo ajax que esta dentro de DataTables({}); recolecta los datos y debería cargarlos en la tabla.

Comment: @Daniel, No es a lo que me refiero, debes tener una etiqueta `<scrip type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" ...></script>`  y otra `<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>` ¿En que orden las tienes?  **Nota:** (No deben ser exactamente iguales a las que coloque pero deben servir de referencia)

Comment: @Robinson debido a que el sistema lo estoy desarrollando utilizando la plantilla de AdminLTE utilizó el puglin que viene con esa plantilla. Agregare una imagen del código.|

Comment: @Daniel deberias probar pasandole un arreglo a tu `DataTable` y no un json.

Comment: @David081 intente pasando un array y sigue dando el mismo error.